# Visual Studio Team Services Deploy to onpremise

Tags: release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

1) Is it possible to Deploy the successfully built Code from VSTS to on premise server(DEV,QA,PROD(Multiple Servers here) ?

Any articles on links on how to set it up

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
In the release defintion create multiple environments, each having the dedicated steps. Then on the three dots next to the environment name click on "deployment conditions" and then in the trigger select "after successful deployment to other environment" and check the environments that should be deployed before the current one.
[image: screen capture of environments triggers]